# INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint ef core

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to insert new record into uploads table and got this error when save changes called:

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Uploads_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "FileSharingDb", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.
> The statement has been terminated.

This is upload code:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(InputUpload model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var newName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(model.File.FileName);
        var fileName = string.Concat(newName, extension);
        var root = env.WebRootPath;
        var path = Path.Combine(root, "Uploads", fileName);

        using (var fs = System.IO.File.Create(path))
        {
            await model.File.CopyToAsync(fs);
        }

        await db.Uploads.AddAsync(
            new Uploads
            {
                FileName = fileName,
                ContentType = model.File.ContentType,
                Size = model.File.Length.ToString(),
                UserId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).ToString()
            });

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: You should add the models that you are using so we can easily see the relationship between the tables. But this means that you are trying to insert a value into a database with a foreign key that does not exist in the fk table

Comment: You are trying to something into the Uploads table with an AspNetUser.UserId that is either null or does not exist in the AspNetUsers table at all.

Comment: As xtryingx said, it is better to share the related models, so that we can know the relationship between them. Besides, to save the related Data, we could use the navigation property. You could refer the following articles: [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key), [Configuring Relationships](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-many-relationship-configuration) and [Saving Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data).